# How does one use SWT without eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, widget, swt

I want to use swt to make GUIs but I do not want to use eclipse to program. Is there anyway to do this. Also,are there any GUI designers for swt that are not eclipse plugins.

Comment: Have you thought about using NetBeans? i believe it has simular tools to SWT. If you could expand your question we might eb able to help more. Why do you not want to use Eclipse? also do you mean "GUI designs" rather than "GUI designers" Im not really certain what you are looking for

Comment: I have a very old computer and eclipse is very slow on it.

Answer (score 5):

Sure it is possible to use SWT independently from Eclipse-RCP platform. You just need to have appropriate jars. Check out these examples http://www.eclipse.org/swt/snippets/. For instance:

```
import org.eclipse.swt.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.*;

public class Snippet169 {
public static void main (String [] args) {
    Display display = new Display ();
    final Shell shell = new Shell (display);
    shell.setLayout (new FillLayout ());
    Listener listener = new Listener () {
        public void handleEvent (Event e) {
            Control [] children = shell.getChildren ();
            for (int i=0; i<children.length; i++) {
                Control child = children [i];
                if (e.widget != child && child instanceof Button && (child.getStyle () & SWT.TOGGLE) != 0) {
                    ((Button) child).setSelection (false);
                }
            }
            ((Button) e.widget).setSelection (true);
        }
    };
    for (int i=0; i<20; i++) {
        Button button = new Button (shell, SWT.TOGGLE);
        button.setText ("B" + i);
        button.addListener (SWT.Selection, listener);
        if (i == 0) button.setSelection (true);
    }
    shell.pack ();
    shell.open ();
    while (!shell.isDisposed ()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch ()) display.sleep ();
    }
    display.dispose ();
}
}
```

Also SWT designers are not bound to Eclipse plugins, just google to find a right one. Example of SWT designer for Eclipse (but not only for Eclipse plugins): http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/

Answer (score 0):

You have to install Eclipse to your computer, but you can copy the SWT JAR files from Eclipse to your other editor's classpath.

I don't think that there are any non-Eclipse SWT GUI designers.

Comment: Cant I just download the swt zip from the swt site and unzip it into my editors path?

Comment: @user1659754: Sure, you can get the SWT JAR files that way.

Comment: You can get the jar for your platform from http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.2-201206081400/#SWT for example.

Answer (score 0):

SWT is independent of eclipse. You can use it for RCP/SWT Based Application or also as J2SE/SWT based application. In 1st case you would use it with Eclipse Equinox OSGi and add dependency to org.eclipse.ui*..., in second case you need to download platform specific SWT*.jar library and put it into your classpath of J2SE application.

I would better now preffer RCP/SWT development, as its much more pluginable and modular, as usage of J2SE.

I preffer more Eclipse IDE instead of the others, just because I simply started 1st with Eclipse (even if I also tried Netbeans or InteliJ) - but this is matter of choice of every developer which IDE to use.

After some playing with SWT & JFace you will simply be possible create GUI even without WindowBuilder -> I do use WindowBuilder but after code is generated, I always change code by myself, but its good tool of course.